# XNA | C# : Record and Change the Voice

Tags: xna, voice, voice-recording

My aim is code a project which records human sound and changes it (with effects).
e.g : a person will record its sound over microphone (speak for a while) and than the program makes its like a baby sound.

This shall run effectively and fast (while recording the altering operation must run, too)

What is the optimum way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: What platform are you aiming for? PC? WP7?

Comment: For pc, actually it does not matter, XNA has both features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for either XNA or DirectX to do this for you, I'm pretty sure you're going to be out of luck (I don't have much experience with DirectSound; maybe somebody can correct me).  What it sounds like you want to do is **realtime digital signal processing**, which means that you're either going to need to write your own code to manipulate the raw waveform, or find somebody else who's already written the code for you.

If you don't have experience writing this sort of thing, it's probably best to use somebody else's signal processing library, because this sort of thing can quickly get complicated.  Since you're developing for the PC, you're in luck; you can use any library you like using P/Invoke.  You might try out some of the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471621/any-good-free-c-dsp-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761212/any-good-c-c-dsp-library).

Comment: upvoted by me, thanks for the answer. realtime digital signal processing is what i need, i already found a library using with PInvoke. I think I shall close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has some info about the Audio namespace from XNA, and the audio recording introduced in version 4:

- [Working with Microphones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634515%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx)
- [Recording Audio from a Microphone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827802%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx)

Keep in mind that recorded data is returned in PCM format.

Comment: unuseful links ... Recording is already done, but with this Audio namespace the things i want are impossible to do.

Comment: Why? Microphone.Default.GetData allows you to retrieve the raw recording data, and with this you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Not all i want. Check the members of Audio Classes. I can change only Pan and Pitch values. A sound has more properties. XNA is built on Directx, but it does not hold all features of Directx.